# Hide submit button after server validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have found this online:

```
function submitButtonClick(button) {
        if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            if (Page_ClientValidate() == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        button.style.display = 'none';  // disable won't work 
        return true;
    }
```

I am not good with Javascript so I couldn't tell what to change...I have a usercontrol with a few buttons, including a submit button. And they are used on every page of my site. And on some pages I have customvalidators. So when a custom validator doesn't validate, the button is gone and there is nothing left to do. What should I change here for the things to work the way I need? Thanks

Comment: `button.disabled = true;`

Comment: try button.style.visibility='hidden';

Comment: if you read again my post maybe you will understand that that is not the problem. display none or visibility hidden or disabled true (though the javascript the way I found it on the internet, later tested it, sais clearly "// disable won't work"...my problem is that after server validation the button disappears, I want it to stay there if there were some server validation problems